# automatically add to vimrc

Tags: vim, vimrc

I had a simple question, but I've been having trouble finding any answers to it.

Is there any command for automatically modify my vimrc from command mode? Specifically, say I wanted to always have word wrap off. Currently, I would appendo update

```
set nowrap
```

to my vimrc. If I wanted it only for the specific file, I would do

```
:set nowrap
```

in command mode. Is there anyway I could do something like

```
:set! nowrap
```

to modify it permanently, i.e. to update my vimrc with that command. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Blindly appending configuration stuff to your `~/.vimrc` won't scale well; you run the risk of accumulating multiple (same or contradicting) config settings over time.

Many users instead have a shortcut (command or mapping) to quickly open their `~/.vimrc` (see [Open vimrc file](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file)) to edit it, and maybe even automatically reload it ([Change vimrc with auto reload](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_vimrc_with_auto_reload)).

Answer (score 1):

For a global setting there's always `:! echo set nowrap >> vimrc`

For per-file settings there are `modelines` (see [vim tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) or man pages). 
Place a line `# vim: set nowrap` (using any suitable comment character)
in the first few or last few (usually 5) lines of the file.